# Why did some early Shuttle missions launch to high inclinations?

Tags: orbital-mechanics, space-shuttle

Most of the Shuttle missions pre-ISS launched to ~28 degrees, due to the latitude of Kennedy Space Center. However, several of the early missions launched to higher inclinations:

- [STS-1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/STS-1), [STS-2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/STS-2), and [STS-3](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/STS-3) launched to ~38 degrees.
- [STS-9](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/STS-9) launched to 57 degrees.

Some later missions also launched to high inclinations, although this may be due to their scientific payloads, most notably Spacelab:

- [STS-41-G](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/STS-41-G) launched to 57 degrees.
- [STS-51-B](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/STS-51-B) launched to 57 degrees.
- [STS-51-F](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/STS-51-F) launched to 49.5 degrees.
- [STS-61-A](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/STS-61-A) launched to 57 degrees.

So what motivated the choice of high-inclination orbits on these missions? For the Spacelab missions, was that the deciding factor in launching to 57 degrees?

Answer (score 9):

For the early test flights, it was to increase the chance of making it to the abort landing site at Rota, Spain (~36.6 deg latitude).

STS-9 included earth observation objectives, hence the high inclination to increase what was overflown.

The other flights you list were for payload objectives: 41G, deploying the Earth Radiation Budget Satellite, for example.

Now I must look for references :)

Comment: I'd love to find some Flight Design documents from those early missions, or at least some requirement definition documents. No luck yet.